# Filter generates a topology compatible with the vector structure of $X$.

Tags: topological-vector-spaces, filters

Let X be a Haudorff Topological Vector Space.

Define the following relation on the collection of all Cauchy filters on X:

$F ∼_R G$ ⇔ $∀U$ nbhood of the origin in $X, ∃A ∈ F, ∃B ∈ G$ s.t. $A − B ⊂ U$.

We define $\hat{X}$ as the quotient of the set of all c.f. on X w.r.t. the equivalence relation (R).

Hence, an element $\hat{x}$ of $\hat{X}$ is an equivalence class of c.f. on $X$ w.r.t. (R).

Let $U$ be an arbitrary nbhood of the origin in X. Define
$ \hat{U}:= \{ \hat{x} ∈  \hat{X} : U ∈ F  \text{ for some } F ∈  \hat{x}\}$.
and consider the collection
$ \hat{B} := \{ \hat{U}: U \text{ nbhood of the origin in } X \}$.

The filter generated by $ \hat{B} $ fulfills all the properties in this theorem

> A filter $F$ of a vector space $X$ over $K$ is the filter of
>   neighbourhoods of the origin w.r.t. some topology compatible with the vector
>   structure of X if and only if
>
> 1. The origin belongs to every set $U ∈ F$
> 2. $∀U ∈ F, ∃V ∈ F$ s.t. $V + V ⊂ U$
> 3. $∀U ∈ F, ∀λ ∈ K$ with $λ \ne 0$ we have $λU ∈ F$
> 4. $∀U ∈ F$,$U$ is absorbing.
> 5. $∀U ∈ F, ∃V ∈ F$ s.t. $V ⊂ U$ is balanced.

How can I check this?

I try to do this but cant because I am new reader in Topological Vector spaces.

Please help me.

Comment: What's $\hat x$ and $\hat X$?

Comment: please, see my edit.

Comment: You probably want to include some basic assumption on what $X$ is. Is it a topological vector space? Is it a Banach space, etc. etc.

Comment: Let X be a Haudorff t.v.s..

Comment: Then [edit] this in.

Comment: Edit was done .